# How do I clone a repo to a remote server using ssh

Tags: git, repository, push

I have two servers, A and B. A has the repo and can ssh to B. B is a new server I want to have the repo, but cannot ssh to A. I've tried copying the repo, create a remote to push, git clone with a -u... any suggestions?

Comment: If you don't have ssh access, what kind of access *do* you have? As long as you have some sort of (possibly indirect) filesystem access, all you have to do is copy files...

Comment: What I mean is that server B cannot reach server A due to a firewall. A is an internal development server and B is an external server for consultants to review.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way which'll set B up as a remote to A, would be to install gitosis on B and then push the repo from A to B.

For more on gitosis, see http://scie.nti.st/2007/11/14/hosting-git-repositories-the-easy-and-secure-way. If you're using git but not gitosis, you're missing out!

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a look at gitosis and see what I'm missing out on.

Comment: I installed gitosis and was able to push the repo to the external server. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Create empty repository on B

```
B$ git init --bare repo.git
```

then push to it from A using SSH protocol

```
A$ git push ssh://B/full/path/to/repo.git
```

Comment: Hm so I tried this...

B$ git init --bare external

A$ git push ssh://user@B/full/path/to/repo.git

I get that these messages:

No refs in common and none specified; doing nothing.
Perhaps you should specify a branch such as 'master'.
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly

Comment: @user481826: I am sorry, I mixed up simpler to use but more complicated to set-up approach where you create "remote" configuration for pushing from A to B with URL-based config-less approach, where you have to specify branch(es) to push, or use `--all`/`--mirror`.

Comment: A$ git push ssh://B/full/path/to/repo.git '*:*'

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean when you say you've tried copying? Have you tried using `scp` like so?

```
scp -R path/to/repo/on/A user@B:desired/path/to/repo/on/B
```

Note that the path following `:` is relative to the user's home directory unless it begins with a `/`.

Comment: I've tried copying the repo over, both with scp and tar the folder first. I can get the files there, but then when I try a git log of the new repo, there are fatal errors.